# Konvajs: Text height doesn't appear in stage.toJSON() if it equals to fontSize

Tags: konvajs

After creating a Text node:

```
const text = new Konva.Text({
  x: stage.width() / 2,
  y: stage.height() / 2,
  width: 200,
  fontSize: 30,
  height: 30,
  fill: 'green',
  text: 'Simple text'
});
```

where **height** value is equal to **fontSize** value, then function `stage.toJSON()` doesn't return **height** parameter:

```
[object Object] {
  attrs: [object Object] { ... },
  children: [[object Object] {
  attrs: [object Object] { ... },
  children: [[object Object] {
  attrs: [object Object] {
    fill: "green",
    fontSize: 30,
    text: "Simple text",
    width: 200
  },
  className: "Text"
}],
  className: "Layer"
}],
  className: "Stage"
}
```

Here is a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/hikobiceji/1/edit?html,js,console

But if **height** and **fontSize** is not equal:

```
const text = new Konva.Text({
  x: stage.width() / 2,
  y: stage.height() / 2,
  width: 200,
  fontSize: 30,
  height: 30.01,
  fill: 'green',
  text: 'Simple text'
});
```

then **height** parameter is present:

```
[object Object] {
  attrs: [object Object] { ... },
  children: [[object Object] {
  attrs: [object Object] { ... },
  children: [[object Object] {
  attrs: [object Object] {
    fill: "green",
    fontSize: 30,
    height: 30.01,
    text: "Simple text",
    width: 200
  },
  className: "Text"
}],
  className: "Layer"
}],
  className: "Stage"
}
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/jiriqikeka/1/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the internal logic of `Konva` serialization. `Konva` is trying to make the JSON as small as possible. So it doesn't include default values of properties.

The height of the text will be equal to its font size if the text is placed in one line. In your case default getter returns `30`. Since it is equal to the value that you used, Konva will skip it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it's clean.